# mongoose creating null document after using module export in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I was recently using a function to upload files to a mongodb database successfully. However after moving those functions into a file (to clean up) and exporting that file then requiring it in my route, the database now creates documents with only null values like so:

```
_id:ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
name:null,
value:null,
image:null,
desc:null
```

I don't know what might be causing this, I am logging the argument object that i'm trying to insert from inside the function 'insertProducts' and the item.name is not null. Sorry I'm new to mongodb :/
maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

CRUD.js

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


const removeProducts = function(req,res){
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost', (err, client) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      let db = client.db('account-app');
      let products = db.collection('products');
      let users = db.collection('users');

      try{
        products.remove({ _id: req.body.id }, function(err) {
          if (!err) {
                  console.log('removed item')
          }
      });
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log('Error while inserting', err)
      }
      client.close()
      res.redirect('/addItems')

    })
  }


  const insertProducts = function(item,res){

    console.log("item name",item.name)
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost', (err, client) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      let db = client.db('account-app');
      let products = db.collection('products');

      try{
        products.insertOne(item)
        console.log('item inserted')
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log('Error while inserting', err)
      }
      client.close()
      res.redirect('/admin/addItems')

    })
  }

  module.exports={removeProducts: removeProducts, insertProducts: insertProducts}
```

my admin route that requires the crud functions

```
const crudOps = require('../utils/admin/CRUD') //require CRUD functions

// Adding new items
// --------------------------------------------------
router.post('/addNewItems', (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.body.name)

let item = {
  name:req.body.name,
  file: binary(req.files.image.data),
  value: req.body.value,
  desc: req.body.desc
}

crudOps.insertProducts(item, res)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That connection URL looks wrong. Generally, it has the format:

> mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase

Try replacing the connection string with the appropriate one for your database and see if that works. Also, the docs normally have `insertOne` statements like this so maybe that is the issue?

```
products.insertOne(item, function(err, r) {
  console.log('item inserted')
  res.redirect('/admin/addItems')
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The records are actually populating in the db in the correct location in the above code they are simply null in value.

Comment: Hmmm, and you are sure that req.body is populating the item correctly?

Comment: Yes as logging req.body.name gives me the name attribute of the object I’m passing in. I at first thought that there might be an issue with the function running before my item (that I’m passing) finished being created however, since my req.body.name is properly defined inside the function after being passed in, wouldn’t the database record’s name field at least not be null?

Comment: @monsterpiece did you try that updated `insertOne` with the `db.close()` in the callback?

Comment: I did move around my db.close() and that seemed to resolve the problem for me! It seems like my server was somehow hanging between the connection and the insertion due to my ordering of the calls.